# The form submitted did not originate from the expected site on EC2

Tags: php, tomcat, amazon-ec2, zend-framework

I am new to PHP and trying to migrate a PHP zend based web application into AWS EC2. I got the following error while try login to the site after migration.

```
The form submitted did not originate from the expected site
```

Tools stack:

- AWS EC2 Linux
- PHP 7.4
- Apache Tomcat 2.4

From my investigate it may be related to CSRF origin issue but I don't know how to fix it. So I would appreciate it if Anyone could share any solution with me here.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to PHP development and this issue. After searching a lot and doing many trial and error ways I found the fix. I used the HTTP protocol and changed it to HTTPS and ten the issue fixed for me.